# Symfony: Request $request not working for form

Tags: forms, symfony

I am fairly new to symfony so I have no idea whats going wrong in this situation.

I have a home page that displays all events in a table. Above that I have a form that acts as a filter for the table which takes a start and an end date. When the user submits the form it should get the dates from the form and put them into variables which I then pass to the twig template to use further.

Now my problem is that for some reason my request doesn't work how I thought it should work. The `return $this->redirect($referer);` Throws this error:

> Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController::redirect() must be of the type string, null given, called in /var/www/symfony/src/Controller/EventController.php on line 39

which I thought was quite weird that it is null as my request should have the referer in its query? Also if I just change the redirect to manually got to `'/'` then it doesn't even enter the if-clause that checks if the form was submitted which leads me to believe `$eventFilterForm->handleRequest($request);` also doesn't work.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong

```php
class EventController extends AbstractController
{
    
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="events")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request): Response
    {
        $start = null;
        $end = null;

        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Event::class);
        $events = $repository->findBy([], ['start_date' => 'ASC']);
        
        $referer = $request->query->get('referer');
        
        $eventFilterForm = $this->createForm(EventFilterType::class, []);
        $eventFilterForm->handleRequest($request);
        if ($eventFilterForm->isSubmitted() && $eventFilterForm->isValid()) {
            $start = $eventFilterForm->get('start_date')->getData();
            $end = $eventFilterForm->get('end_date')->getData();

            return $this->redirect($referer);
        }

        return $this->render('event/index.html.twig', [
            'eventFilterForm' => $eventFilterForm->createView(),
            'events' => $events,
            'end' => $end,
            'start' => $start,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `HTTP_REFERER` value is stored in the `headers` not in the querystring, `$request->headers->get('referer')` - *sidenote:* It is still possible this value is empty/null, so you'd need to verify it

Comment: @DarkBee oh yeah that worked. I assume this kind of request is different from ```Request::createFromGlobals();``` then? Cause there it works with query instead of header